# Why isn't a 'git fetch' from within the submodule necessary before a 'git submodule update'?

Tags: git

We have Wordpress installed as a submodule in our web project. We are a team of 5 with a shared repo. The production server is deployed from the master branch of the shared repo.

When I or another team member wants to update the wordpress core we cd into the wordpress submodule on our local machine and run 'git fetch' followed by checkout version. We then commit the change in the super project and push the commit to the shared repo.

However when we deploy our website on the production server the Capistrano deployment script fails with:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree
```

The deployment script runs the following commands:

```
git fetch -q origin
git fetch --tags -q origin 
git reset -q --hard (latest commit)
git submodule -q init
git submodule -q sync
export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive)
git submodule -q update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE
git clean -q -d -x -f
```

From my research I believe the tree object which the commit references does not yet exist within the submodule on the web server. I would assume then that the deployment script needs an extra step which first cd's into the submodule folder and runs a 'git fetch' before the 'git submodule update' command is run. However I can't find anyone else using 'git fetch' in their submodule workflow. What am I missing? Is the solution to add the '--recurse-submodules' switch to the 'git fetch' commands?

**UPDATE** I thought the problem may be related to the version of git (1.7.1 on Centos 6) running on the server so we upgraded to 1.7.11 but the problem still persists.

Comment: Does this script fail on the `git submodule -q update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE` line?

Comment: capistrano should be able to resolve this itself when you use `git_enable_submodules`

Comment: @JohnnyZ: I can't tell, Capistrano runs all those commands at the same time using '&&'

Comment: @phoet: We already have 'set :git_enable_submodules, 1' in the deploy script. Anything else we can check?

Comment: @Michelle we used that option without any problems :( did you try deleting the submodule and re-init it? there might be some corruption in the git repo.